# Using qplot() in R: y label is not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using qplot, but am having difficulty adding a label to the y-axis. I am using + ylab("My y label") to the end of my qplot functions. It does not cause an error. A plot is generated, but the y label cannot be seen.

Here is toy data:

```
x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
y=c(7,2,6,3,9)
xstart=c(5,2,7,3,6)
ystart=c(1,4,5,8,2)
xend=c(4,7,2,7,3)
yend=c(4,6,8,3,8)
diagx=c(1,-1,1,-1,1)
diagy=c(-1,1,-1,1,-1)
myLab=as.factor(c("text1","text2","text3","text4","text5"))
df=data.frame(x,y,xstart,ystart,xend,yend,diagx,diagy,myLab)
```

And my code to generate the plot (notice the last line):

```
myPlot = ggplot2::qplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, label=myLab, geom="text", vjust=-.25, hjust=.5) +
  ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x=xstart, y=ystart, xend=xend, yend=yend),inherit.aes=F) + 
  # Draw the underline of the variety
  ggplot2::geom_segment(ggplot2::aes(x=xend, y=yend, xend=diagx, yend=diagy),inherit.aes=F) +
  #ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variety, scales="free", ncol=2) +
  ggplot2::scale_size_continuous(range=c(3,3),guide="none") +
  ggplot2::scale_colour_identity() +
  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title=ggplot2::element_blank(), 
                 axis.text=ggplot2::element_blank(), 
                 axis.ticks=ggplot2::element_blank()) + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(expand = c(.1, 1.075)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(.1, 1.075)) +
  ggplot2::ylab("My y label")
```

If you have any advice, please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: When you're using many functions from the same package, it's better to just load the package with `library(ggplot2)` then you don't need all the `ggplot2::` (most of the time)

Comment: You're setting `axis.title` to `element_blank()`. What did you expect to happen? Remove that.

Comment: @jlhoward: Thanks, but when I simply remove that line, I also get the default character "x" on the x-axis, which I do no want. I guess it is a hack, but it seems that removing it, and then typing ggplot2::ylab("My y label") +
ggplot2::xlab("") works.

Comment: Why is that a hack? `ggplot` defaults the x-title to the x-aesthetic and similarly for y. If you want to change the defaults, you have to change them. You can also use `labs(x="",y="whatever...")`, but given your horrific syntax, it doesn't seem as though you mind the extra typing...

Comment: It's not a hack, it's a perfectly sensible way to get your result.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks for your comment. I am developing a package, and when I run R CMD check(), I am advised to use the ggplot2:: syntax. It is horrific-looking, but my colleagues say it is necessary/advisable.